# linux shell: Concatenate instruction and file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How do I concatenate the following alias (in .bashrc) with the file located in ~/Downloads/?

```
alias inst=`instruction ~/Downloads/`
```

I want to run the command in this way:

```
inst file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to achieve is not directly possible with an alias.

Indeed, the approach you suggest

```
alias inst='instruction ~/Downloads/'  # with single quotes, not backquotes!
inst file
```

will amount to

```
instruction ~/Downloads file  # with a space
```

Instead, you can consider adding a function in your `.bashrc`:

```
inst() {
    instruction ~/Downloads/"$1"
}
```

Then, run the command in this way:

```
inst file
```